# How to fix PHP Warning: file_exists(): File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on this platform (260)?

Tags: php, tinymce, file-exists

As you can see below I am using WYSIWYG `tiny_mce` with ibrowser. I am getting this error:

```
> PHP Warning:  file_exists(): File name is longer than the maximum
> allowed path length on this platform (260):
> C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\demos.xxx.com\qa\xxx\assets\js\plugin\tiny_mce\plugins\ibrowser\scripts\phpThumb\cache\5\56\56b\56b7\phpThumb_cache_demos.xxx.com__src56b72e3bbea26ba9aec8b0449cabc81d_par0b9e73569dbbfe81d5e1ff2a11d92887_dat1389704510.jpeg
> in
> C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\demos.xxx.com\qa\xxx\assets\js\plugin\tiny_mce\plugins\ibrowser\scripts\phpThumb\phpThumb.php
> on line 588
```

At **line 588**:

```
    if (is_writable(dirname($phpThumb->cache_filename)) || (file_exists($phpThumb->cache_filename) && is_writable($phpThumb->cache_filename))) {

            $phpThumb->CleanUpCacheDirectory();
            if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($phpThumb->cache_filename) && is_readable($phpThumb->cache_filename)) {
                chmod($phpThumb->cache_filename, 0644);
                RedirectToCachedFile();
            } else {
                $phpThumb->DebugMessage('Failed: RenderToFile('.$phpThumb->cache_filename.')', __FILE__, __LINE__);
            }

        } else {

            $phpThumb->DebugMessage('Cannot write to $phpThumb->cache_filename ('.$phpThumb->cache_filename.') because that directory ('.dirname($phpThumb->cache_filename).') is not writable', __FILE__, __LINE__);

        }
```

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: By not creating paths/filenames that exceed this limit of course.

Comment: that is not a choice, is there any other solutions??

Comment: there must be something else that I can use instead of file_exists that will not show this warning

Comment: @PeeHaa it is not a practical solution

Comment: OK perhaps you think switching to another FS is more practical.

Comment: @Waqleh  Are you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply the advice of the message. Rearrange your files' structure.

Comment: this can't be the only solution

Comment: Of course there is, but it is not practical solution to ask him to change the platform. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: rearranging file structure is not practical, maybe I can use something other that file_exists!